# how to schedule job every month first monday at 10 o'clock in salesforce?

Tags: scheduled-apex

can you please give me the example of above scenario.How to solve above solution please give some ideas.

Comment: Have you tried google, the exact requirement is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Use "Schedule Future Runs" and choose "Monthly - On the 1st Monday of every Month"

Comment: can please give me the example on that

Comment: That is how you do it through the UI. If that doesn't answer your question .. consider improving your question with more specific details.

Comment: yeah, I think I misunderstood 'report' with 'apex job' In case of later my solution does not apply of course.Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use the below Corn expression to schedule batch job.

Global Void Execute(SchedulableContext sc)

{

System.schedule('Monthly', '0 0 10 ? * 2#1', new BatchclassName() );

}

This  '0 0 10 ? * 2#1'  means at 10am on each first monday of the month.

First 0 : represents "Seconds"

Second 0 : represents "Minutes"

Third 10 : represents "Hours"

Fourth ? : represents "Day-of-month" . Here "?" is given not to specify any day of month.

Fifth * : represents "Month" Jan-Dec. Here * means every month.

Sixth 2#1: represents "Day-of-Week" . Here 2 means "Monday" and "#1" means every 1st week.

Hope this helps you.

Thanks!

Comment: how write the code give one example on that

Comment: Write your batch class and schedule it with Schedulablecontext sc method as I have provided in my answer above. Again posting it here.

Comment: Global Void Execute(SchedulableContext sc)

{

System.schedule('Monthly', '0 0 10 ? * 2#1', new BatchclassName() );

}